# How to Get latitude & longitude when get turn in Android

Tags: android, geolocation

I work on application of distance calculator in which I want to calculate total distance traveled. I got some tutorial in which location get periodically. I know how to get location periodically but I want take location(i.e latitude & longitude) when user get turn while traveling.
 So I want to know how to user got turn with device so that location should get acquire.For simplicity see the following image in which I want get location of point `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I.`
  [image]

Any Further suggestion for distance calculation will appreciate.
Thank You.

Comment: If you can get locations periodically, then you could hypothetically grab locations regularly. You could compare two close locations, and if getBearing() result was above a threshold, it would indicate a turn just occurred and you could then (perhaps) identify the location of a turn?

Comment: @iaindownie: yes you are right, but If I go periodically the take a scenario at point F & I, if it takes location at point F and then directly take location at point I then it calculate straight distance between point F & I.

Comment: Question just says can "get location periodically", nothing about confined to particular points. If you can get location every 10m (extreme example), you can detect turns (relatively) accurately.

Comment: @iaindownie: Ok then how to get location at 10m distance?

Comment: How are you getting any location from the line at the moment?

Comment: @iaindownie: by using class LocationManager, Loaction and Interface LocationListner

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35148/discussion-between-iaindownie-and-samadhan-medge)

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve new location coordinates in a pretty fast rate (for example every second). So use the getBearing()-method every second and then I think you will be able to get every turn if you do a constant comparison with the previous values!

You could also try to calculate a mean bearing-value for the last couple measurements so that you do not exceed your threshold so quickly and identify many corners that you do not want to identify... (these false positives depend on the quality of the GPS and also for example on the environment, because GPS is easily influenced by buildings etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I new to this topic can you tell me how to use getBearing() method to calculate.

Comment: getBearing() returns to you the current heading of your movement/device in degree (example: 90° if you move east). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing%28%29 so you can use this to calculate whether the bearing changed significantly in order to determine a corner...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I trying on it but it gives 0.0 direction, I also use sensorSimulator for changing direction, shall I try on real Device.

Comment: Hello, I want some help, below I have 11 locations and their bearing then how to compare bearing and get turn? Locations:-19.994886,73.741565
19.997346,73.741729
19.997366,73.742183
19.998072,73.74615
19.998636,73.749712
20.001016,73.749669
20.001257,73.7519
20.000733,73.753917
20.007508,73.75499
20.007105,73.759625
19.998475,73.768895  Bearing:-3.6060154
87.33176
79.337234
80.490555
-0.9784346
83.48032
105.3669
8.5141535
95.25472
134.5615

Comment: Well just look at the bearings: you have -3, then 87, then 79, then 80, then -1... these are the headings you are facing. so apparently, you turned 90° from the first to the second measurement, and then again 90° in the other direction between the fifth and the sixth measurement...

Answer (score 1):

For calculating the distance, it's not necessary to specifically detect turns in the user's way. With LocationManager you can get locations e.g. every seconds. Just sum up the distances between those locations and you're done.

It makes no difference to the distance if you've only position E and F or if you've got 3 extra locations under way.

It may happen that you miss the exact corner, but the LocationManager can provide locations pretty fast, so that's no big problem and the GPS positioning isn't *that* exact anyway.

**Calculating the distance between two Locations**

To calculate the distance between two `Location` objects, use [`Location.distanceTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) which will give you the distance in meters.